# Polymer ready function still too late

Tags: jquery, polymer

Inside an Polymer element, I am trying to call some function before any content is loaded. I tried to put this function in

```
ready: function(){...}
```

But it is called **after** the content starts to load.

Unfortunately, I am not able to move my function to the outside of this Polymer element into `index` page. But this Polymer element is the first element in the `index` page.

So what is the correct way to make my function executed before anything is loaded? i.e. I need something that get executed as early as jQuery function `$(document).ready()` or I need someway to block any content loading until this function is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The way you could try doing this is using the different element lifecycle functions that are invoked before DOM is initialized or other callbacks.

If you are using Polymer 1.x try doing it in the `created` callback which is called when the element has been created, but before property values are set and local DOM is initialized (so you can't read attributes or manipulate DOM in this callback but you can set up some ground work).

1.x Reference: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements

2.x Reference: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4108#issuecomment-258983943